# How to use the answerSDP returned from sdm.devices.commands.CameraLiveStream.GenerateWebRtcStream to establish a stream with google nest cam

Tags: webrtc, nest, nest-device-access

I'd like to be able to use the stream from my nest cam (battery) in a home automation project, storing video streams and/or snapshops from the stream.  I have successfully connected my devices using homeassistant to prove it is possible, and have leaned heavily on the code from [python-google-nest-sdm](https://github.com/allenporter/python-google-nest-sdm).

I am attempting to stream live video from the nest cam (battery) device using  [sdm.devices.commands.CameraLiveStream.GenerateWebRtcStream](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream#generatewebrtcstream).  I have successfully connected to my devices, sent an sdpOffer and received a response from the sdm.  I am struggling to build a working stream from the answer.

> {
> "results": {
> "answerSdp": "v=0\r\no=- ...\na=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024\r\n",
> "expiresAt": "2021-12-21T21:45:27.779Z",
> "mediaSessionId": "C..F"
> }
> }

I have followed code from various other projects and tried using aiortc from python eg. [aoirtc](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/main/examples/datachannel-cli/cli.py), and javascript examples from eg [WebRTC](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/)

The closest I have got is following the code from [googlelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0) inserting the answerSdp into the remotePeer, but I am getting an error and I am sure I am not establishing the local and remote peers correctly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the sample app?  It might help with getting that sorted.  https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/samples/web-app

Comment: Thanks @BTGunner.  I was able to work this out.  For me, it was doing this to the peerconnection:
> setRemoteDescription({"type" : "answer", "sdp" : result.results.answerSdp})